# Is the following function surjective or injective?

Tags: functions

$f:\{-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4\} \to \mathbb Z, f(n)=n^2-n-1$, is it injective or surjective?

I believe it isn't surjective but I'm not sure why. I know it isn't injective as some elements in the domain map to the same elements in the codomain, so it isn't 1-1.

Comment: This is not clear.  Is the domain of $f$ just those $8$ numbers or is it all of $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @lulu the domain of f is the 8 numbers, yes, and $\mathbb Z$ is the codomain!

Comment: So...how could  $8$ numbers surject onto an infinite set?

Comment: That's what I thought, I just doubted myself as when I input it into Wolfram Alpha it said it still wasn't surjective with the domain being the set of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Well, that quadratic has an absolute minimum, for example.

Comment: $-5/4$ if I'm not wrong? I'm not sure what that shows though.

Comment: It means that there isn't even a real number $x$ such that $f(x)=-2$, for example.